# Is the Borel reduction of an hyperfinite equivalence relation still hyperfinite?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Let $(X,E)$, $(Y,F)$ be Borel equivalence relations. Assume $(X,E)\leq_{\text{B}}(Y,F)$.${}^{\dagger}$ Does it hold that: $F$ hyperfinite $\Longrightarrow$ $E$ hyperfinite?${}^{\ddagger}$ I do not see how to prove this in an obvious way at least, since the Borel reduction does not provide an injection.

---

${}^{\dagger}$ That is, there is a (not necessarily injective) Borel man $\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$, which reduces the equivalence relation on $X$ to that on $Y$ as follows

$$(\forall{x,x’\in X})\quad{x’~E~x\Longleftrightarrow \varphi(x’)~F~\varphi(x)}.$$

${}^{\ddagger}$ A Borel equivalence relation $(Z,R)$ is said to be **hyperfinite**, exactly when there is a nondecreasing $(R_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ of finite Borel equivalence relations on $Z$, so that $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}R_{n}=R$.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of "finite Borel equivalence relation"? I imagine it means something like "finitely many non-singleton classes".

Comment: An equivalence relation $(Z,R)$ is called a **Borel equivalence relation**, exactly in case $R\subseteq Z\times Z$ is Borel. An equivalenc relation $(Z,R)$ is called a **finite equivalence relation**, exactly in case every class is finite. Lemma: let $(Z,R)$ be a Borel equivalence relation, in which every class is infinite. Then $(Z,R)$ is hyperfinite if and only if there is a Borel action $\mathbb{Z}\times Z\rightarrow Z$ which generates $R$, i. e., $R=E^{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}}=\{(x,y)\mid(\exists{g\in\mathbb{Z}})gx=y\}$, the orbit equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer is **no**. The argument is as follows: Equality on a Polish space is a finite Borel equivalence relation; so it is enough to reduce some equivalence relation with big classes to equality in order to get a counterexample.

Readily, take $Y:=\{0,1\}$ (discrete), $F=\mathrm{id}_Y$, $X$ any space with a nontrivial clopen partition into two pieces, and $E$ the relation given by this partition. For example, $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ with the relative topology of $\mathbb{R}$, and $E:=[0,1]^2\cup [2,3]^2$. Now the map that sends $[0,1]$ to $0$ and $[2,3]$ to $1$ is a continuous (*a fortiori,* Borel) reduction of $E$ to $F$.

Comment: True, I thought about this today and came up with possibly the simplest example. Let $X$ be an uncountable Polish space with the trivial equivalence relation $E=X\times X$. The map $X\rightarrow 1$ is a Borel reduction. The latter is hyperfinite, but the former is not, as the classes are not countable. The requirement of injectivity in the definition of reduction is thus necessary for equivalence relations to inherit hyperfinitude ($\ldots$ but Borel reductions by definition are not required to be injective.)